# Unable to configure remote Nexus Helm repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm, artifactory, nexus

On Artifactory 6.16.2 I'm trying to cache a remote Nexus Helm repository. When I enter the URL of the repository I'm getting an error in UI and logs:

```
Error occurred while performing folder replication for 'helm:' to 'https://repo.myhost.com/repository/helm': Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory instance: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory instance: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

I also tried with https://repo.myhost.com/service/rest/repository/browse/helm/. This does not give an error in the UI but it does in the logs. Also `Unable to identify target URL as an Artifactory`.

I enabled the option to bypass HEAD requests, no difference.

Are remote Nexus Helm repositories supported?

--EDIT--

Adding some screenshots of our configuration
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it possible to show repo config details?

Comment: @newuserua_ext sure! I added some screenshots

Comment: thx @Charlie . looks like "index.yaml" is missing. can you please check and try the following link steps: https://jfrog.com/blog/master-helm-chart-repositories-artifactory/

Comment: @newuserua_ext thanks, I read through that page but my repository is a remote repository. We also have a virtual repo which includes the remote one but recalculating the index is only an option on local repositories which is not applicable in this case.